# Disk usage monitoring for EC2 Spot instance with CloudWatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

CloudWatch metric became invalid after Spot instance got replaced.

Is there a way to update the existing alarm with new instance_id instead of creating a new alarm?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-what-is.html) source that gets triggered whenever a spot instance is created and have the target call a Lambda function to update the alarm via the [put-metric-alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html) command.